# how i can make a input responsive in css

Tags: html, css

i cant fix this problem (in screen shot)

[image]

[image]

i mean why it dosent being responsive

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="big-card col-xl-12 col-l-12 col-md-5 col-s-3 col-xs-3 ">
      <input class="btn " type="submit" value="خرید گیفت کارت">
      <div class="big-card-txt col-xl-5 col-l-5 col-md-5 col-s-3 col-xs-3">
        <h2 class="big-card-txt h22">آیا شما نیاز به اپل آیدی دارید؟</h2>
      lorem
      
     </div>
        
         
        
      <img src="apple-dev2.jpg" alt="" class="apple-dev img-res ol-xl-12 col-l-12 col-md-5 col-s-2 col-xs-2">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please show your CSS.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the goal is. Currently it is not clear what exactly you want to achieve and how the elements should behave.

Comment: Can you post a snippet code ? We cannot debug images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
input {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-self: center;
}
.big-card-txt{
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}
.big-card {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="big-card col-xl-12 col-l-12 col-md-5 col-s-3 col-xs-3 ">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="big-card-txt col-xl-5 col-l-5 col-md-5 col-s-3 col-xs-3">
      <h2 class="big-card-txt-h2 h22">آیا شما نیاز به اپل آیدی دارید؟</h2>
      lorem
    </div>
    <input class="btn " type="submit" value="خرید گیفت کارت">

  </div>
    <img src="https://s6.uupload.ir/files/magearray-giftcard-icon_s4qk.png" alt="" class="apple-dev img-res ol-xl-12 col-l-12 col-md-5 col-s-2 col-xs-2">
  </div>
</div>
```